# List-comprehension - default first value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to set a default-first value in list-comprehension (Python 3.7)

```
array = [" " , node for node in set_nodes]
```

so my output would be

```
[' ', 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

I know I could just say

```
[" "] + [node for node in set_nodes]
```

but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution?

Comment: I guess you could even do `[' '] + set_nodes` in that particular case.

Comment: I feel that would be the only option you have. You are simply inserting an item at the start of the list, and that isn't really dependent on any of the list items.

Comment: It's possible that there is a more elegant situation at the spot where this list would be _used_. Maybe you don't need to make this list.

Comment: You could do `array = [' ', *[element for element in source]]`, but in your case there is no need to iterate over the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just unpack your original list into a new list with the first element as your default element

```
set_nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3]
default = ' '
array = [default, *set_nodes]
print(array)
```

The output will be

```
[' ', 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Another option is to add the element before the first element of the original list via slicing. One benefit here is you can change your slice parameters to insert a list of defaults

```
set_nodes[:0] = default
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just insert element:

```
set_nodes = [0, 1, 2, 3]
set_nodes.insert(0, " ")
print (set_nodes)
```

output:

```
[' ', 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

One more possible way is to use chain of itertools:

```
from itertools import chain 
a = [1, 2, 3]
[i for i in chain(['any_default_value', 'multi?', 'no problem'], a)]  
# ['any_default_value', 'multi?', 'no problem', 1, 2, 3]
```

which I think it is especially useful when you want to execute comprehension containing if condition.

Looks like `chain` is pretty suitable for comprehension :-)